# I can't find the uploaded photo taken from phonegap camera api in remote server image folder

Tags: php, cordova, mysqli

I can't find the uploaded photo taken from phonegap camera api in remote server image folder. The name of the photo such as "23497678900.jpg is saved in my mysql table, but the actual photo is not saved in the server folder specified.

Below are the codes I used to capture, upload and at the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Submit form</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}


// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

    // Show the selected image
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = imageURI;
}


  // A button will call this function
  //
 function getPhoto() {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
  }

  function uploadPhoto() {

    //selected photo URI is in the src attribute (we set this on getPhoto)
    var imageURI = document.getElementById('smallImage').getAttribute("src");
    if (!imageURI) {
        alert('Please select an image first.');
        return;
    }

    //set upload options
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    options.params = {
        firstname: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
        lastname: document.getElementById("lastname").value
    }


    options.headers = {
      Connection: "close"
    };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://hostname.com/image/upload.php"), win, fail,

 options);
}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function onFail(message) {
  console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    alert("Response =" + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="getPhoto();">Select Photo:</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" /><br>

<form id="regform">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="uploadPhoto();">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

upload.php code is:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "pw";
$database = "mydbase";

 $con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database) or die ("Could not

connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());

 $firstName2=$_POST["firstname"];
 $lastName2=$_POST["lastname"];

//storing file in filename variable
 $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "image/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target);

$sql = "INSERT INTO postinfo (firstname,lastname,imgfile) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ('$firstName2', '$lastName2', '".basename($_FILES['file']'name'])."')";

if($con->query($sql)){
echo "Your comment has been sent";
}
else{
echo "Error in sending your comment";
}
?>
```

I've ran out of ideas on what else to do to get the actual image uploaded into the image folder in my server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue in your PHP script with the `$target` variable. If you have access to the root directory of the server, you will probably find your images in `/image`.

If you want the images in the same directory as the script, you will need something more like:

```
$target = dirname(__FILE__) . '/image/';
```

Comment: Actually $target is in the root folder.

Comment: I have access to the root directory of the server but there is no photo in the folder.

Comment: Are the permissions of that folder set in a way that PHP has access to write?

Comment: I used to check for the content of the folder through file zila and the user permission is set at numerical vaule = 755.

Comment: I would try `775` or you could change the owner of the directory and see if either of those help

Comment: Pls thanks so far. I tried 777 yet it's not working. Let me also try 775 to see the out come.

Comment: It's now working after I chmod the file to 777. Thanks Dawson Loudon.